# How to import and export MongoDB indices to JSON with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've got a situation where I need to maintain identical indices on MongoDB databases between environments, but I can't use mongodump/restore because I don't want to copy the data, I just import and export the indices as JSON docs.  I need a handy way, preferably using Pymongo, to export the indices for all collections in a given Db (or all DBs on the instance) into a single JSON file, then be able to take that file and apply the indices to another instance to ensure all the DB names, collection names, and indices on those collections are identical between environments (I'd also like to be able to maintain collection cap limits if they exist as well).

Does anyone have a handy code example that does this?  Would you use db.collection.index_information() and if so, how would you encode the output into a JSON doc that could be later read by the same script and imported into another instance?

Comment: If I understand it well, you need to copy the _schema_ but not the _data_ ?

Comment: Are you going to do the migration in a single script, or you need to dump the index data, and then execute another script which will apply these indexes on another MongoDB instance?

Comment: Right, I need to be able to export the "schema" (such as it is in mongodb), store it in a JSON file, and then be able to import that JSON to a fresh instance of mongo such that all DBs, collections, caps, and indices are identical.

Comment: Ideally I'm planning on one script with different arguments for import and export.

Comment: You need to copy: DBs, collections, users, roles, indexes. Did I missed something ?

Comment: In my case users and roles are irrelevant.  I just need DB names, collection names, collection caps, and indices.  No actual data/document contents.  Thats highly variable between environments.  In export mode, this script should just create the proper Dbs, collections, caps and indices such that they will be correct before any data is written to the new instance.

Comment: Part of the problem is that starting in 3.0, I can't use mongoexport to simply export system.indexes into a portable JSON like so:

`mongoexport -h localhost -d MyDB -c system.indexes --jsonArray -o MyDB.indexes.json`

I need a way to do this, as well as get information about any caps on collections so that I can copy the "schema" of a DB without also capturing the data.